# Python Selenium cant find xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

Need help finding the `xpath` for the text inside the class ('Click Me Now').

[image]

I have tried this so far :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Click Me Now"]')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/button[@class="ScCoreLink-udwpw5-0 fOmFQF tw-link"]')
browser.find_element_by_class_name('ScCoreLink-udwpw5-0 fOmFQF tw-link').get_attribute()
```

None of them worked.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Also, try this xpath: `//button[contains(text(),"Click Me Now")]`

Comment: @Dhamo Tried that too. I get this error : Exception has occurred: NoSuchElementException
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(text(),"Click Me Now")]"}

Comment: Have you tried `'//button[contains(.,"Click Me Now")]'` ? What about not uppercased text?

Comment: Are you able to locate with above xpath in DOM? and are you sure no other element blocking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"Click Me Now")]')`  or
`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(.,"Click Me Now")]')`
However it's possible that the actual text inside the element is `click me now` or something else and it is formatted by the JavaScript so if the `xpath`s above will not work for you try `click me now` instead of `Click Me Now`

Answer (score 0):

You are putting only one backslash instead of two. This should work

`element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="ScCoreLink-udwpw5-0 fOmFQF tw-link"]')`